# Initialize an array of struct within a struct

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, nodejs, arrays, struct

I am working on a use case of "Purchase Order" wherein there will be multiple Products listed/ordered under one Purchase Order(PO) by a buyer.

1 PO : N Products

```
struct Product{
    bytes32 product_code;
    bytes32 product_name;
    uint quantity;
    uint unit_price;  
}

struct PurchaseOrder{
    bytes32 po_number;
    string po_creation_date;
    // next line is the question
    mapping( bytes32 => Product[]) products;  // or Products[] products
}

//mapping to store Purchase Orders
mapping(uint => PurchaseOrder) purchaseOrders;

uint po_number = 100;

function createPO(string memory po_creation_date,bytes32[] memory products) public returns(bool){

    require(msg.sender == buyerAddress);
    po_number++;
    purchaseOrders[po_number].po_creation_date = po_creation_date;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        bytes32[] memory arr=new bytes32[](products.length);
        arr[0]= products[i];
        //bytes32 product_code = arr[0].product_code;
        purchaseOrders[po_number].products[product_code].push(Product(arr)); // how do i need to proceed ??
    }

}
```

parameter **bytes32[] memory products**  comes from nodejs app and as a array of objects.

I must also be able to retrieve all the products under *a* PO for particular buyer.

Improve this code or if this code does not make sense and can be rewritten to achieve same, please feel free to do so or guide me.

*TiA*

Comment: There's no question here!

Comment: title says it all.. still, in createPO function i'm getting "products" as array of Objects. Now, how do i set it in products array available in PurchaseOrder struct also in turn set values from products into Product struct.    1 purchaseOrder holds multiple products/line item @goodvibration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Improve this code or if this code does not make sense and can be rewritten to achieve same, please feel free to do so or guide me.

Issues:

1. This will not scale to larger Purchase Orders because it contains an O(n) loop. https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad
2. The data structure doesn't map to my idea of a PO which would be one-to-many Header to Line Items, and one-to-one Line Items to Products.
3. A mapping alone is not iterable, so that means there would be no way to enumerate the Products in the Purchase Order - probably not acceptable.

Consider:

1. Create data structure with PO Header => LineItem (with qty, other attributes) => Product.
2. Amortize the work with smaller O(1) steps, e.g. create header, append line item.
3. Push the iteration of line items outside the contract. This way, a client can initiate many small operations, as needed, and never run out of gas.

If you want to offer an append-only process for adding Line-Items, a simple array will work. If you want CRUD operations before commitment, use Mapped Structs with Index and Delete: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

By "commitment" I mean finalized PO should not be altered but during the creating process you have multiple steps, so you'll probably want a "finalize" function to conclude the editing of the draft PO and carry on with the finalized document.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for insight on issues and to be taken care of things. I didn't get this point clearly "PO Header => LineItem (with qty, other attributes) => Product" . can you provide an example as such ? @Rob Hitchens

Comment: You seem to be saying a PO contains a set of Products. In practice, they tend to contain a set of line items, and each line item has a product, how many, and possibly other details. Like 2 hamburgers, 1 nachos and 3 beers is an order. `LineItem{ qty:n, product: id}`. The order has header info and n Line Items. Don't let me over-complicate it if the quantity is always 1 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this example may fit for you:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract StructArrayInit {
  
  event OnCreateRoom(address indexed _from, uint256 _value);
  
  struct Room {
    address[] players;       
    uint256 whosTurnId;
    uint256 roomState;
  }  
  
  Room[] public rooms;

  function createRoom() public {
      Room memory room = Room(new address[](0), 0, 0);
      rooms.push(room);
      rooms[rooms.length-1].players.push(msg.sender);

      OnCreateRoom(msg.sender, 0);
  }
  function getRoomPlayers(uint i) public view returns (address[]){
      return rooms[i].players;
  }
}
```

This example addresses the issue of not having a way to iterate through a map.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/39208)

Comment: I've just edited the answer. I think now it may add some wisdom as a response.